# comments_number not displaying

Tags: comments, comments-template

[Live site](http://urbanpalate.com/blog/)

I'm using `<?php comments_number( $zero, $one, $more ); ?>` on `home.php` to display number of comments in the post-meta. Problem is, it's not showing the number despite there being one comment on that post. Any ideas what's causing the problem?

Here's post-meta for `index.php`:

```
<div class="post-meta">
                <p><?php the_date(); ?> | <?php the_tags('tags:', ', ', '<br />'); ?> | <?php comments_number( $zero, $one, $more ); ?> comments</p>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
            </div><!-- end post-meta -->
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the code you're using from

```
<div class="post-meta">
    <p><?php the_date(); ?> | <?php the_tags('tags:', ', ', '<br />'); ?> | <?php comments_number( $zero, $one, $more ); ?> comments</p>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
</div><!-- end post-meta -->
```

to

```
<div class="post-meta">
    <p><?php the_date(); ?> | <?php the_tags('tags:', ', ', '<br />'); ?> | <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?> comments</p>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
</div><!-- end post-meta -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace `$zero`, `$one`, and `$more` with your own code;
read the example in the Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number#Examples